# How to prevent a cable going off a caster wheel pulley?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

When pulling a cable to the sides at large angles it has a tendency to come off a caster wheel pulley, how could you prevent it from sliding off the pulley?

Comment: care to add a sketch or image?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, with guards like these:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Often these guards/guides will have rollers on all 4 sides of the guide box in order to reduce friction when the cable is pulled at an odd angle...